# Go: How can I define a one function for similar structures

Tags: go

I have this

```
type File struct{}

type FileRead struct {
    File
}
type FileWrite struct {
    File
}
type CppRead struct {
    FileRead
}
type CppWrite struct {
    FileWrite
}

func (f *File) Open(name string, mod string) {
    fmt.Println("open", name, mod)
}
func (f *FileRead) Open(name string)  { f.File.Open(name, "read") }
func (f *FileWrite) Open(name string) { f.File.Open(name, "write") }
func (f *CppRead) Open(name string)   { f.FileRead.Open(name + ".cpp") }
func (f *CppWrite) Open(name string)  { f.FileWrite.Open(name + ".cpp") }

func main(){
    cpp := &CppWrite{}
    cpp.Open("main")
}
```

I don't like it because there are two functions that doing the same thing:

```
func (f *CppRead) Open(name string)
func (f *CppWrite) Open(name string)
```

I can rewrite them as

```
func (f *CppRead) CppOpen(name string)   { f.Open(name + ".cpp") }
func (f *CppWrite)CppOpen(name string)   { f.Open(name + ".cpp") }
```

So they become more similar, but still there are two

I know that i can use an interface

```
type FileRWOpener interface {
    Open(string)
}
func CppOpen(file FileRWOpener, name string) {
    file.Open(name + ".cpp")
}
func main() {
    cpp := &CppWrite{}
    CppOpen(cpp, "main")
}
```

But i want to use it as

```
cpp.Open("name") // not CppOpen(cpp, "main")
```

Comment: Unless you see some large benefit from having the function add the file extension you could get rid of `(f *CppRead) Open` and `(f *CppWrite) Open` and just use `CppOpen(cpp, "main.cpp")`

Comment: It's just a minimal example, in a real program it makes more useful work.

Answer (score 2):

Go does not have pure object inheritance, I think you can only put the common business logic in a private package function and call the function in the two implementations of the method Open.

```
func changeFileName(name string) { return name + ".cpp" }
func (f *CppRead) Open(name string)   { f.FileRead.Open(changeFileName(name)) }
func (f *CppWrite) Open(name string)  { f.FileWrite.Open((changeFileName(name))) }
```

This is a very simple example, the business logic could be more complex.